# Why does the contractibility of $CX$ imply that $\pi_n(CX,X,x_0)\cong\pi_{n-1}(X,x_0)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

My Algebraic Topology notes say that because the cone of $X$ is contractible (which is easy enough to see, $H([x,t],s)=[x,t(1-s)]$ does the job) the Long Exact Sequence of Relative Homotopy Groups gives $\pi_n(CX,X,x_0)\cong\pi_{n-1}(X,x_0)$. I however fail to see how exactness gives us the required conclusion. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a piece of the long exact sequence, we have:

$$ \pi_n(CX) \to \pi_n(CX,X) \to \pi_{n-1}(X) \to \pi_{n-1}(CX)$$

the first and last terms are zero by the contractibility of $CX$. This implies that the middle map is an injection and surjection of groups, and therefore an isomorphism.

Comment: For $n = 1$ the middle map is just a function between pointed sets. It is surjective because $\pi_0(CX) = 0$, but I think we need an additional argument for injectivity.